# Term reference field: Checkboxes with add new textfield

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I need to change the presentation of a Term reference field. Drupal 7 has 3 widget types:

- Select list
- Check boxes/Radio buttons
- Autocomplete term widget

I need to display check boxes to select 1 or many terms when adding a node, but I also need to display a textfield to allow adding new term.

The autocomplete term widget allows to choose existing terms and add new ones, which is the functionality I need, but what I exactly need is a list of checkboxes with the existing terms and the textfield below that allows adding a new term.

I've searched modules, but I can't find one that allows me to do this. Is there a module that performs this? If not, how do I do this in code? Is there any way to customize the widgets to create that functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://drupal.org/node/1208512#comment-5605324

It has been adapted from [Select or other](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) to support taxonomy term references.

It is a non-contrib module and you may need to tweak it to your taste, especially as it adds Other: to the term you have added. I just tried it out and that part needs to be fixed, but it shouldn't be difficult.